# How to override Django Q() model?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-orm

I want to query like this in Django ORM

```
from django.db.models import Q
MyModel.objects.filter((Q(flag=True) & Q(model_num__gt=15)) | (Q(flag=True) & Q(model_num__lt=7)))
```

Are there any way I can restrict the (Q(flag=True) & Q(model_num__gt=15)) results to only first query element?

Do we need to override Q model or we are having another apporach?

Comment: You mean if there no values with the first filter then only check the second filter?

Comment: No I want to return only first value from first filter.